# Trapping a post data binding event for Silverlight

Tags: c#, data-binding, events, silverlight-3.0

I have a series of controls that are created at run-time and then added to my Silverlight application layout grid. I was wondering if there was some sort of event that I could trap AFTER data binding has occurred. I would like to do some post processing on the controls after data has been bounded from the `DataContext`.

I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but that only gives me access to the properties of my model upon change, but I would rather have access to the individual user-control object.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now the only event fired that I can see post binding would be the control's `Loaded` event. So currently I just do my post processing when this event is trapped.

If anyone else has any better suggestions I am all ears.

```
TextBox text = (TextBox)uiElement;
text.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_Loaded);

private void TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    // do more post processing... 
}
```